# Frames, vb6, disabling controls?

Tags: textbox, vb6, frame

How do I use the DIRTY property in VB6? I have a form that gets loaded with data from SQL-SERVER on form_load. I have to detect the changes that are made anywhere on the form and disable a button. Where would I include the dirty function?

Comment: What platform are you using? Winforms, Access Forms, other?

Comment: Not sure, its a VB6 application.

Comment: Then `VB.Net` does not apply.

Comment: What if they want to abort their changes?

Comment: In that case they will click CANCEL and it will repopulate the controls with original values.

Answer (score 1):

the quicker way is to handle Text_Change event

```
'Private Sub Text1_Change()
'    cmdEXIT.Enabled = False
'End Sub

Private Sub Text1_Change(Index As Integer)
    cmdEXIT.Enabled = False
End Sub
```

as you can see, group of textbox handle better this situations

Comment: yeah but I have to do this for all the textboxes. I thought there might be a quicker way of doing it. Thanks!

Comment: as i said, make group of textboxs ,you will write code only once

Comment: I don't know how, I know that I can do a handler for all textboxes but i dont know how

Comment: you have to do some training :). for that create a test project, create a text box  and a button, rename the button cmdEXIT, leave the text box as is. now copy the text box and paste it on the form it will prompt you if you wish to create group of cnontrols, confirm that, you have now two textboxs. copy the code above and paste it on the form source. execute

Comment: How would I do it if my textboxes are already on the forms, not in a control group. I have about 35 textboxes and 17 comboboxes and I'm just looking for a way to do it without re-doing all that.